# Add hours, minutes and seconds to date via Javascript then display on title

Tags: javascript, date, time, title

I have a simple script that is supposed to show you the current date and supposed to leave a message based on the date. I am trying to get it so that I can display it, but also show that because the next month is upcoming, lets say the 25th and later, it would say that the next month is coming up. I am also not sure how to use a setinterval() to make the time look like its counting.

So far, this is what I have:

```js
var message1 = "Have a nice week!";
var message2 = "The weekend is almost here!";
var message3 = "Enjoy the weekend !";
var dateText = "";


function output() {
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  dayValue = today.getDay();
  var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd
  }
  if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm
  }
  todaysDate = (mm + "/" + dd + "/" + yyyy);

  if (dayValue == 0) {
    dateText += "Sunday";
    document.write("Today is: " + dateText + " " + todaysDate + " " + message3);
  }
  if (dayValue == 1) {
    dateText += "Monday";
    document.write("Today is: " + dateText + " " + todaysDate + " " + message1);
  }
  if (dayValue == 2) {
    dateText += "Tuesday";
    document.write("Today is: " + dateText + " " + todaysDate + " " + message1);
  }
  if (dayValue == 3) {
    dateText += "Wednesday";
    document.write("Today is: " + dateText + " " + todaysDate + " " + message1);
  }
  if (dayValue == 4) {
    dateText += "Thursday";
    document.write("Today is: " + dateText + " " + todaysDate + " " + message2);
  }
  if (dayValue == 5) {
    dateText += "Friday";
    document.write("Today is: " + dateText + " " + todaysDate + " " + message2);
  }
  if (dayValue == 6) {
    dateText += "Saturday";
    document.write("Today is: " + dateText + " " + todaysDate + " " + message3);
  }


}
```

```html
<body onLoad="output()" ;></body>
```

Thank you.

Comment: So what is the problem? There are many questions here already on countdown timers and clocks using *setTimeout* and *setInterval*. Once you've had a go, ask a specific question about an issue you're having.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use [`moment js`](https://momentjs.com).  In **moment js**, it is providing so many method for customisation like [`format`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/), [`date`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/date/), [`weekday`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/weekday/) and so many methods are available.

You can use on basis your requirements.

Here is below, I have created a demo, I hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.

```js
var msg = ["Have a nice week!", "The weekend is almost here!", "Enjoy the weekend !"], // As per your reuirement I have just only put into array.
    weekDays = moment.weekdays(), //it will return all the weekname
    date = moment(); //this will return today date

//this function will return text basis of week day number
function getMsg(d) {
    let weekMsg = '';
    switch (d.day()) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
            weekMsg = msg[0];
            break;
        case 4:
        case 5:
            weekMsg = msg[1];
            break;
        default:
            weekMsg = msg[2];
    }
    return weekMsg;
}


//this function will put log on console..
function putConsole(d) {
    console.log(`Today is : ${weekDays[d.day()]}, ${d.format("DD MMMM YYYY hh:mm:ss a")} ${getMsg(d)}`);
}


document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = `Today is : ${weekDays[date.day()]}, <b id="timer">${date.format("DD MMMM YYYY hh:mm:ss a")}</b> ${getMsg(date)}`

setInterval(function() {
    date.add(1, 'seconds');
    document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = date.format("DD MMMM YYYY hh:mm:ss a");
}, 1000)

putConsole(moment('2018-03-11')); //For Sunday
putConsole(moment('2018-03-12')); //For Monday
putConsole(moment('2018-03-14')); //For Wednesday
putConsole(moment('2018-03-15')); //For Thursday
putConsole(moment('2018-03-16')); //For Friday
putConsole(moment('2018-03-17')); //For Saturday
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.7.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<div id="title"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use setInterval to call your output function periodically, and then call that function onload.

Find the solution in the attached snippet.

```js
var message1 = "Have a nice week!";
var message2 = "The weekend is almost here!";
var message3 = "Enjoy the weekend !";


function setOutput(){
  setInterval(output, 3000);
}
function output() {
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var dayValue = today.getDay();
  var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  var hh= today.getHours();
  var MM= today.getMinutes();
  var ss= today.getSeconds();
  var dateText = "";
  
  if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd
  }
  if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm
  }
  var todaysDate = (mm + "/" + dd + "/" + yyyy + " "+hh+":"+MM+":"+ss);
  var titleElement = document.getElementById("title");
  
  if (dayValue == 0) {
    dateText += "Sunday";
    titleElement.innerHTML = "Today is: " + dateText + " " + todaysDate + " " + message3;
  }
  if (dayValue == 1) {
    dateText += "Monday";
    titleElement.innerHTML ="Today is: " + dateText + " " + todaysDate + " " + message1;
  }
  if (dayValue == 2) {
    dateText += "Tuesday";
    titleElement.innerHTML ="Today is: " + dateText + " " + todaysDate + " " + message1;
  }
  if (dayValue == 3) {
    dateText += "Wednesday";
    titleElement.innerHTML ="Today is: " + dateText + " " + todaysDate + " " + message1;
  }
  if (dayValue == 4) {
    dateText += "Thursday";
    titleElement.innerHTML ="Today is: " + dateText + " " + todaysDate + " " + message2;
  }
  if (dayValue == 5) {
    dateText += "Friday";
    titleElement.innerHTML ="Today is: " + dateText + " " + todaysDate + " " + message2;
  }
  if (dayValue == 6) {
    dateText += "Saturday";
    titleElement.innerHTML ="Today is: " + dateText + " " + todaysDate + " " + message3;
  }


}
```

```html
<body onLoad="setOutput()" ;>
<div id="title"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a different message at the end of the month, you just need to get the date using [`getDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) and do a comparison, `(new Date()).getDate() >= 25`. As for creating a clock, you just create a function that updates the time on the page and then call it with [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval). `setInterval` is really easy to use, you just pass a function to run, and an interval (in milliseconds). It returns the id of the timer that it creates, which you can store if you want to later stop the timer using [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval). In the example below, I am using [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) to format the date instead of building up a string like your code does or using a library like moment.js like another answer suggested. [`document.write` should be avoided](http://www.uselesscode.org/blog/posts/spotting-bad-javascript-tutorials/#code-that-uses-document-write-), instead I am creating a separate element on the page for the message and the date/time and updating them independently when needed.

```js
// the updateTimer variable will hold a function
// that is returned by this IIFE
const updateTimer = (function () {
  let lastDate;
  
  const elMotd = document.getElementById('motd');
  const elDateTime = document.getElementById('datetime');
  
  const dateOptions = {
    weekday: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'numeric',
    day: 'numeric',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    second: 'numeric'
  };

  // return the function that will be stored in the global
  // updateTimer variable.
  // the `now` parameter defaults to a date object representing
  // the current time/date if updateTimer is not passed any arguments.
  return function updateTimer (now = (new Date())) {

    let currentDate = now.getDate();
    
    // only update the message of the day if
    // the date has changed (or this is the first run
    if (currentDate !== lastDate) {

      lastDate = currentDate;

      let motd;
      // using a switch instead of multiple if/then statments
      // can make things much simpler and easier to read
      switch (now.getDay()) {
        // Thur - Fri
        case 4:
        case 5:
          motd = "The weekend is almost here!";
          break;
        // Sat - Sun
        case 6:
        case 0:
          motd = "Enjoy the weekend!";
          break;
        // Mon - Wed
        default:
          motd = "Have a nice week!";
      }

      if (currentDate >= 25) {
        motd = 'It is almost a new month. ' + motd;
      }
      elMotd.textContent = motd;
    }

    elDateTime.textContent = now.toLocaleString('en-US', dateOptions);
  }
}());

// run updateTimer immediately so we don't have to wait one second
// for the first update
updateTimer();
// start a timer to update once a second
let timer = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);

// the stuff below here is just here for the example
document.getElementById('first').addEventListener('click', () => {
  clearInterval(timer);
  let d = new Date();
  d.setDate(1);
  updateTimer(d);
}, false);
document.getElementById('twentysixth').addEventListener('click', () => {
  clearInterval(timer);
  let d = new Date();
  d.setDate(26);
  updateTimer(d);
}, false);
```

```css
div {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  border: #ccc solid 1px;
}
```

```html
Today is: <span id="datetime"></span> <span id="motd"></span>

<!--the stuff below here is just here for the example -->
<div>
  Stop timer and...
  <button type="button" id="first">Set date to the first of the month</button>
  <button type="button" id="twentysixth">Set date to the 26th of the month</button>
</div>
```